# Fetching pictures using Instagram API ordered by nr of likes

Tags: api, instagram

As the title describes, is there (perhaps an undocumented)  way to fetch pictures using Instagram API ordered by nr of likes?

Answer (score 0):

In short: no.

You can of course call the images with the [/tags/tag-name/media/recent](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) endpoint (which will return the amount of likes per pic), store in a DB and then sort by likes, etc...